# How do I remove the scroll from just one window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 2 different windows and I want to keep the scroll only in one of them. I've posted the xaml code where the scroll can be found, the code that triggers when the user selects and image, and also a few illustrative screenshots. I hope I made myself clear. If you need more details, don't hesitate to ask

```
 <k:KinectScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" Name="scrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="wrapPanel" Orientation="Vertical" k:KinectTileButton.Click="KinectTileButtonClick">


            <Image Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" />
```

Code2:

```
protected void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;

        if (button.Tag is WineGroupModel)
        {
            C1 C1 = new C1(); //mainwindow
            C1.ImagesDir = (button.Tag as WineGroupModel).WinesDir;


            C1.Show();
        }
        else if (button.Tag is WineModel)
        {
            var wineModel = button.Tag as WineModel;
            var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(wineModel);
            this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException("Unkown Wine object type");
        }
    }
```

http://i62.tinypic.com/34dfk2v.jpg

Comment: Your question is too vague. On your screenshot we can only see what looks like the same application, launched two times. So on what condition do you want to show the scrollbar, and on what condition do you want to hide it ?

Comment: i want to make it visible only when needed.. it should have the auto property

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, in your CodeBehind, you can show/hide the scrollbar, with

```
this.scrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = // Visible or Hidden
```

Comment: The name 'Visible' does not exist in the current context.this is the error I get.. I don't I should set as Hidden there..